# phonegap on android says: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/app/fb.js

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova

I load my main page using super.loadUrl("http://myURL/app.html");
and in app.html I have lines like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="file:///android_asset/www/app/fb.js"></script>
```

When I run it on device I get the following error in LogCat:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/app/fb.js

Comment: Isn't there anybody who knows the answer? I really need to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Chnage the src of the script tag src="app/fb.js"